# How do I store a variable in the session from the browser using angular.js?

Tags: session, angularjs

I need to add a key to my session object on the browser using angular.js. Is this possible?

Comment: server session or browser storage?... question is quite vague

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change your session from client side.

Comment: it is if OP asking about `sessionStorage`... but not clear at all what is wanted

Answer (score 0):

If you mean changing client-side session `window.sessionStorage` then just ad key-value with the object.

Otherwise if you want to change server-side session this needs some work.
I assume you use some MVC framework. First create an action in a controller which logic should add key-value passed by parameter to you session. Map the action to some path. On client-side you should create service which makes $http.post call to that action path and value as data.

Security hint: Please don't parametrize key name unless you have some security checks server-side. This way malicious user won't be able to modify sensitive key-value in your sessions.